# how to add a check mark to the selected item in the listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7

i'm new to windows phone 7, I have one doubt:
how to add a check mark to the selected item in a dynamically created listbox. If user clicks another item in the listbox, the check mark will shifts its position to the selected item. how to do it? my code is shown below:
XAML CODE:

```
<ListBox Height="669" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479" Margin="1,-3.5,0,0" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged" Background="White">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1.2" BorderBrush="Black" Width="480" >
                    <StackPanel Background="White" Name="stackpanel1" Width="480" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"  Height="62" Width="390" FontSize="40" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="Black" TextAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

CS code:

```
 public class list
    {
        public string name { get; set; }

    }

foreach (string s in array)
                {
                    list obj = new list();
                    obj.name = s;
                    listBox1.Items.Add(obj);
                }
```

Please guide me with some pieces of code. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 3):

A purely XAML-based solution would be this:

Your application-specific code would be something like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And the style of your listbox would be in XAML terms (copy-paste and change 'someIcon.png' below to the name of the icon you want to use):

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Green"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionIcon">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Border Width="80" Height="80">
                            <Image Name="SelectionIcon" Source="someIcon.png" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

*Update 1:*

Adding an image to illustrate my comment about build action below.

[image]

Comment: Your code is helpful. But it does not show the image. How to change the image visibility? please help me.

Comment: Let's say you are going to use the same image name as in the code above. Then you must add an image with that name ("someIcon.png") to your solution. Ensure that the image is located in the root folder of the solution (i.e. not in some folder of your solution) and is built as content. You do the latter by right-clicking on the image in the Solution Explorer window and selecting Properties. Then for the target of the build-action choose "Content". Then you can build and run the app.

Answer (score 0):

Create a user control for your data template. In your usercontrol add a check image or highlighter and toggle its visibility when the user taps on the corresponding item. Thats what I have done too. I hope it helps.

Something Like below:

`User control`

```
                <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1.2" BorderBrush="Black" Width="480" >
                <StackPanel Background="White" Name="stackpanel1" Width="480" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image x:Name="checkImg" Source="check" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"  Height="62" Width="390" FontSize="40" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="Black" TextAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
                </Border>
```

and the `listbox` now:

```
        <ListBox Height="669" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479" Margin="1,-3.5,0,0" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged" Background="White">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <user:control></user:control>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

In your `selectionchaged` event, extract the item as `ListBoxItem` and toggle its visibility.

Store the selected item s old item, when you select another item, set visibility for old item as false and new item as true.

Comment: How to change the visibility of the image. I tried in the below way:

Comment: ListBoxItem selectedItem = this.listBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(this.listBox1.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;                                                             selectedItem.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; But, it does not visible to me. I wrote this code inside the selectionChanged event. Please help me..

Comment: Use a userControl. Parse the selected item as usercontrol. `UserControl uc = selectedItem as UserControl;` then you will be able to access `uc.checkImg.Visibility = visibility.Collapsed.` For this you should create `UserControl`

Comment: A error occured...... Cannot convert type System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem to System.Windows.Controls.UserControl. help me...Thanks.

Comment: Try this alternative: In your border of usercontrol add tap event and try to alter visibility of that checkImg in that event handler. It should work. The previous should have worked, you must have done something wrong.